# Constructing a table with PHP Function

Tags: php, function, html-table

I am  new to PHP and I want to construct a table with PHP function. I don't know that's my code doesn't work. Please help me.

This is in `tablefunction.php`,

```
class Table {
        private $row = '0';
        private $col = '0';

        function _constructSimpleTable($row, $col){
            echo "<table>";
                echo "<thead>";
                    foreach ($col as $key => $value){
                        echo "<th>".$col."</th>";
                    }
                echo "</thead>";

                echo "<tbody>";
                    foreach ($row as $key => $value){
                        echo "<tr><td>".$row."</td></tr>";
                    }
                echo "</tbody>";

            echo "</table>";
        }
    }
```

And this is in `test.php`

```
include ('./lib/tablefunction.php');

$class = new Table();
$class->_constructSimpleTable(3,4);
```

Please help me where I am going wrong here?

The error message is this

> Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in C:\xampp\htdocs\WeltesLogisticInventory\lib\tablefunction.php on line 10
>
> Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in C:\xampp\htdocs\WeltesLogisticInventory\lib\tablefunction.php on line 16

And my expected output is constructing a table with 3 rows and 4 columns with the number incremented.

Comment: fixed.. sorry about the rush

Comment: `foreach` loops over arrays. You have no arrays. Maybe you didn't want `foreach`? Also, it seems you're forgetting that tables are 2-dimensional: where are your `<td>` elements?

Comment: forget that... ill edit it.. so to iterate should i use for ??

Comment: `$col` is not an array

Answer (score 0):

Your $row and $col is not an array but you use it in foreach loop.

If your expected output like this:

```
1 2 3 4
1 2 3 4
1 2 3 4
```

First 1 2 3 4 row is a header.

```
class Table {
    private $row = '0';
    private $col = '0';

    function _constructSimpleTable($row, $col){
        echo "<table>";
            echo "<thead>";
                for($i=1;$i<=$col;$i++){
                    echo "<th>".$i."</th>";
                }
            echo "</thead>";
            echo "<tbody>";                
                for($i=1;$i<$row;$i++){
                    echo "<tr>";
                    for($j = 1;$j<=$col;$j++){
                        echo "<td>".$j."</td>";
                    }
                    echo "</tr>";
                }             
            echo "</tbody>";
        echo "</table>";
    }
}

$class = new Table();
$class->_constructSimpleTable(3,4);
```